# Making a web server disconnect from the client?

Tags: c++, http, unix

I have a UNIX server program(C++ using C UNIX libraries), which creates, binds to a socket, accept and listen to the client, and once connected takes a request from the client.

Once the request is served, I want to terminate the connection with the client, but do not want to kill the server so that the server can serve other clients.

What is the UNIX function that does this?

Comment: when you accept a client connection, that client is dedicated its own socket. You simply close that socket, which only closes that client's connection. Your original listen socket is not closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `close(2)` on the file descriptor returned by `accept(2)`. The listening socket will remain open until you take other action.

You might find [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) a useful read.

Comment: Oh, I was calling close() outside the loop, thinking it closes the server. Now it works. Thank you.